# Memory getting full by timers or Webbrowser? c#

Tags: c#

Alright, Hello everybody.
First here is my code:
My problem is written bellow the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    Decimal startCoins;
    string winlossstr;
    int TotalRolls;
    int TotalWins;
    int TotalLost;
    int winloss = 0;
    int CountError;    
    private void timerGetData_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            string u = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            u = u.Substring(u.IndexOf("<span id=\"goCoins\" class=\"coins\""));
            u = u.Substring(u.IndexOf(">") + 1);
            u = u.Substring(0, u.IndexOf("</span>"));
            textBoxCoins.Text = u;
            //newCount = Convert.ToDecimal(u);
            label5.Text = u;


            decimal Pstart = Convert.ToDecimal(startCoins);
            decimal Pnew = Convert.ToDecimal(u.Replace('.', ','));
            decimal p = Convert.ToDecimal(Pnew) - Convert.ToDecimal(Pstart);
            labelProfit.Text = p.ToString();
            labelToltalRols.Text = TotalRolls.ToString();

            //if (newCount >= oldCount)
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(label5.Text) >= Convert.ToDecimal(label11.Text))
            {
                textBoxWinLoose.Text = "Won!";
                textBoxWinLoose.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                textBoxWinLossCounter.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                textBoxBetAmount.Text = textBoxAmount.Text;

                winlossstr = "won";
                TotalWins++;
                labelRollsWon.Text = TotalWins.ToString();
                var cl = labelCoinsWon.Text;
                var clbet = textBoxBetAmount.Text;
                decimal clbet1 = Convert.ToDecimal(clbet.Replace('.', ','));
                if (cl == "0")
                {
                    labelCoinsWon.Text = clbet;
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal clc = Convert.ToDecimal(cl.Replace('.', ',')) + clbet1;
                    labelCoinsWon.Text = clc.ToString();
                }
                //DEBUGGER
                richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Roll Number #" + labelToltalRols.Text + " Bet Amount: " + textBoxBetAmount.Text + " Won!");
                richTextBoxHistorik.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Roll Number #" + labelToltalRols.Text + " Bet Amount: " + textBoxBetAmount.Text + " Won!");
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxWinLoose.Text = "Loss!";
                textBoxWinLoose.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                textBoxWinLossCounter.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                winlossstr = "loss";
                TotalLost++;
                labelRollsLost.Text = TotalLost.ToString();
                var cl = labelCoinsLost.Text;
                var clbet = textBoxBetAmount.Text;
                decimal clbet1 = Convert.ToDecimal(clbet.Replace('.', ','));
                if (cl == "0")
                {
                    labelCoinsLost.Text = clbet;
                }
                else
                {
                    decimal clc = Convert.ToDecimal(cl.Replace('.', ',')) + clbet1;
                    labelCoinsLost.Text = clc.ToString();
                }
                //DEBUGGER
                richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Roll Number #" + labelToltalRols.Text + " Bet Amount: " + textBoxBetAmount.Text + " Tabt");
                richTextBoxHistorik.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Roll Number #" + labelToltalRols.Text + " Bet Amount: " + textBoxBetAmount.Text + " Tabt");
            }
            // TIMER
            var r = new Random();
            var r2 = r.Next(3000, 5000);
            timerLoop.Interval = r2;
            decimal t = Convert.ToDecimal(r2) / 1000;
            ////DEBUGGER
            richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Loop starts in " + t + " secs.");
            timerLoop.Start();
            //oldCount = newCount;
            label11.Text = label5.Text;

            timerGetData.Stop();
        }
        else
        {

            CountError++;
            label18.Text = CountError.ToString();
            ////DEBUGGER
            richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Website not found. #" + CountError.ToString());
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
            ////DEBUGGER
            richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Reloader data in 10 secs.");
            timerGetData.Interval = 10000;
            timerGetData.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timerLoop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (winlossstr == "won")
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            doc.GetElementById("bet").SetAttribute("Value", textBoxAmount.Text);
            richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Setting start bet!");
        }
        if (winlossstr == "loss")
        {
            var h = textBoxBetAmount.Text;
            decimal n = Convert.ToDecimal(h.Replace('.', ',')) * 2;
            textBoxBetAmount.Text = n.ToString();
            var j = n.ToString();
            HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            doc.GetElementById("bet").SetAttribute("Value", j.Replace(',', '.'));
            richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Setting loss bet to: " + j.Replace(',', '.'));

        }

        timerClick.Interval = 1000;
        timerClick.Start();
        timerLoop.Dispose();
    }

    private void timerClick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalRolls++;
        HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("id").Equals("roll"))
            {
                el.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
        timerClick.Dispose();
        ////DEBUGGER
        richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Rolled");
        timerRefreshPage.Interval = 2000;
        timerRefreshPage.Start();
    }

    private void timerRefreshPage_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);
        timerRefreshPage.Stop();

        ////DEBUGGER
        richTextBoxDebugger.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") +  " Website loades." + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Getting data in 1 sec");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        timerGetData.Interval = 2000;
        timerGetData.Start();
    }
```

Alright, i have an huge problem with my Memory in this program.
In about an hour running this program my Memory will get fully loaded by this program.
I have tryed to dispose all my timers without any help.

So i have come to that its maybe my Webbrowser there is filling up my memory, my webbrowser is refressing in every 5-10 secs.
I have tried google and on this Stackoverflow to dispose the webbrowser, i found a way where i was creating a new webbrowser for every refresh, but i didnt help on my Memory usage.

I have also worked on to clear my webbrowser cache, but i have to be signed in on the website with a user and a password, so that can't help me either.

So now i want to show you my code and hope someone can tell me what i need to do, so it don't fill up my ram.

And, then i have another thing in this code i cant figure it out why its goes wrong.

Alright, as you can see in the code its finds out if my new data from the website is higher or lower then it was before in this:

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(label5.Text) >= Convert.ToDecimal(label11.Text))
```

But I have seen a few times if it gets lower more then 13 times it's just "reset" the counter so the program thinks that it's not lower anymore, and sets my winlossstr string to "won", even if it's still gets an loss result on the website.

Fyi the data this program gets from the website is a number ex. like this: 125.578

I hope you understand my and my question, otherwise please tell me what you need to know.

Best regards

-- Edit --

Alright, now i have found this:

```
    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SetProcessWorkingSetSize", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr pProcess, int dwMinimumWorkingSetSize, int dwMaximumWorkingSetSize);

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
```

in my timer:

```
    IntPtr pHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
SetProcessWorkingSetSize(pHandle, -1, -1);
```

But that's doesn't help me either, my memory keeps going up. and it won't stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tick methods you always seem to append text to some kind of textbox (`richTextBoxDebugger`), which might take up more and more memory space as you go on. Try to comment out these calls (or at least limit the maximum amount of text tored in that box), to avoid filling up the memory space.

Comment: Hi Bassfader, actually i already tryed that i think, not totally sure.. because i had the same issue before i created that richtextbox, but yea, ill try it later on and says hows it goes., Thx for your answer!

Comment: Alright, i can see your point that the append text is taking some memory space, now after i removed all my debugger texts.. But its not that there is giving the big problem, my memory usage is still going straigt up in usage for every "rolls" there a make, in my eyes it seems to be the webbrowser but i do not now how to hold the memory down in that.. It seems like for every Webbrowser Refesh my memory goes up, not back down..